# How to understand the stochastic process $Y_t=(X_t, t)$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I met some confusion when I was working on the following exercise: $X_t$ is a non-time homogeneous Markov process with state space $E$, prove $Y_t:=(X_t,t)$ is a time homogeneous Markov process with state space $E\times [0,\infty)$. The solution is considering the probability transition kernel of $Y_t$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Q_{t_1,t_2}[(u,r), A\times B]&=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_2}\in A, t_2\in B|X_{t_1}=u, t_1=r)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_{r+(t_2-t_1)}\in A|X_{r}=u)\cdot\mathbb{P}(t_2\in B|t_1=r)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(X_{r+(t_2-t_1)}\in A|X_{r}=u)\cdot\mathbb{P}((t_2-t_1)\in B|0=r)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
So it's only depend on $t_2-t_1$.

My confusion is whether the initial position of $Y_t$ is determined, in other words, if $r\neq t_1$, is such conditional probability well-defined? The time homogeneous Markov property means for any $u>0$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y_{t_2+u}\in A|Y_{t_1+u}=x)=\mathbb{P}(Y_{t_2}\in A|Y_{t_1}=x)
\end{equation}
And now if the initial position of $Y_t$ is determined w.r.t. $t$, $Y_{t_1}$ and $Y_{t_1+u}$ are impossible to start from the same point. For example, $Y_3$ can only start from $(X_3,3)$, $Y_5$ can only start from $(X_5,5)$, $X_3$ can equal $X_5$, but $3\neq 5$. In this case, how to say the time homogeneous Markov property?

In short, is the initial position of $Y_t$ arbitrarily chosen in space? I completely cannot understand the meaning of the transition of this process. And the what's the meaning of $\mathbb{P}(t_2\in B|t_1=r)=\mathbb{P}(t_2-t_1\in B|0=r)$ in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q_{s, t}$, $s\leq t$, be the stochastic kernels from $(E,\mathcal{E})$ to itself such that
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_s]=\mathbb{E}[f(X_t)|X_s]=\int f(x)Q_{s, t}(X_s,dx)$$
for all measurable bounded function $f$ on $(E,\mathcal{E})$.
Since $Q_{s, t}=Q_{s,s+(t-s)}$, by introducing a purely deterministic process $u_t=t$, and looking at $Y_t=(X_t,u_t)=(X_t,t)$, we can create a time homogeneous process on $E\times[0,\infty)$. More explicitly, consider the stochastic kernel
$\tilde{Q}_{s,t}g(x,u)=\delta_{u+t-s}\otimes Q_{s, t}g$ for any bounded measurable function $g$ on $E\times[0,\infty)$.
Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[g(X_{t+h},t+h)|(X_t,t)]&=\int g(x,u)\, \delta_{t+h} \otimes Q_{t,t+h}(X_t,u)\\
&=\int\Big(\int_E g(x,u)Q_{t,t+h}(X_t,dx)\Big)\delta_{t+h}(du)\\
&=\int_Eg(x,t+h)Q_{t,t+h}(X_t,dx)
\end{align}

---

The check that $\tilde{Q}$ is  the correct kernel on $E\times[0,\infty)$, notice that for $g(x,u)=\mathbb{1}_A(x)\mathbb{1}_B(u)$, $A\in\mathcal{E}$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}$, then
\begin{align}
\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[g(X_t,t)|(X_s,s)=(x,u)]&=\tilde{Q}_{s, t}g(x,u)\\
&=\int \mathbb{1}_B(w)\int\mathbb{1}_A(y)Q_s(x,dy)\,\delta_{u+t-s}(dw)\\
&=\mathbb{1}_B(u+t-s)Q_{s, t}(A)=\mathbb{1}_B(u+(t-s))Q_{u, t}(A)
\end{align}
on account that $s=u$. In particular, for $B=\mathbb{R}$, we recover the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, where can I know $Y_t$ is time-homogeneous? As for my question, is the $u$ in $\tilde{Q}_{s,t}h(x,u)$ arbitrary? Does it only make sense when $u=s$?

Comment: @Syruphhh: Notice that for any bounded measurable function $g$, $\tilde{Q_{s, t}}g(X_s,s)$ depends only on $t-s$, and of course on $(X_s,s)$. That is what I showed: $\mathbb{E}[g(X_{t+h},t+h))| (X_t,t)]=F(h,(X_t,t))$.

Comment: @Syruphhh: This is similar to the way one can make autonomous ODEs from nonautonomous: $\dot{x}=f(x,t)$; letting $y(t)=(x(t),t)$, we obtain $\dot{y}=F(y)$ where $F((x,t))=(f(x,t), 1)$. The second component has a "very" deterministic structure that is, once one knows the initial $t_0$, then we know what $t$ is $h$ units of time later: $t_0+h$.